# Do access subforms that are not visible still update/requery? If not, can this be behavior be configured?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an old Access database that is being upgraded to work with Access 2007.  The client is complaining that it is slow now.  I am looking for ways to optimize it.

There is one subform that is in a particular tab on the form.  I have been wondering -- does the subform still update/query even when it is not visible?

If this is configurable --- how?

Comment: Tony, I know this is meta, but I disagree with adding the 2007 tag. It's plainly indicated in the question, and in this case, doesn't change the answer one iota. If the question were specific to an A2007 feature, it would be different, but in this case, I think it adds nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All controls refresh/update whether visible or not.

It's generally considered good practice to not load recordsets until they are needed. If you have many subforms in a tab control, you can use the tab control's OnChange event to load/unload your subforms, or, alternatively, to set the recordsources.

However, with only a couple of subforms, this is not likely to be a big help. But with a half dozen or so, it's a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the recordsource from the subform and add it back when the form is made visible, or simply remove the whole subform and add that back.